# Typecast NSImage to Any and downcast it back to NSImage

Tags: swift, casting, nsimage, any

I'm trying to understand why

```
var tmp: Any = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)
var img: NSImage = tmp as NSImage
```

Will not work and cause an error, but

```
var tmp: Any = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath) as Any!
var img: NSImage = tmp as NSImage
```

will do the job? How's it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, this manages to pack many different issues into a tiny amount of code :-)  This explanation is long so you might find you know the first part of it but may as well start at the beginning...

`NSImage(byReferencingFile)` is what’s called a “failable initializer” – that is, an initializer that returns an `NSImage?` – an optional that might, or might not, contain an `NSImage` object.

The reason being, creating the `NSImage` from the file might fail (suppose the file isn’t found).  For this reason, it returns an optional that you have to check and unwrap:

```
if let img = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath) {
    // img will be a valid NSImage
}
else {
    // img was not valid, handle error here if you want
}
```

Now, if you try and assign an `NSImage?` (as returned by the failable initializer) to a non-optional `NSImage`, you’ll get an error, because you can’t do that – you need to do the unwrap as shown above instead:

```
// error: value of optional type 'NSImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
let img: NSImage = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)
```

One way to handle this, as mentioned in the above error message, instead of unwrapping the image with `if … let`, is to “force-unwrap” the optional, like this:

```
let img: NSImage = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)!
                             // note exclamation mark -^
```

This `!` means: don’t bother checking for nil, just assume the result is valid and unwrap it.  This is *sometimes* a good idea, but usually is a very bad idea.  If you ever force-unwrap a nil value, your program will exit abruptly with an error.  So unless you are 100% certain there is no possible way the value could be nil (which isn’t very common), you should avoid doing this.

OK so how is the `Any!` impacting all this?

A type with a `!` after it is an “implicitly unwrapped optional”.  These are optionals, but that you don’t have to manually force-unwrap.  You can just access them like regular values – but again, if you ever access a nil value, your app will quit.

So you could write the following:

```
let img: NSImage! = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)
// or, this is basically the same thing:
let img = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath) as NSImage!
```

Now you could use `img` *as if* it weren’t an optional.  But if it were ever nil, as before, it would crash.  The difference being, it will crash when you *use* `img`, not when you assign it to `img`.

Finally, `Any` is a type that can hold any kind of type, but is pretty useless without getting the real type back out.  You should usually do this with `as?`.  `as?` checks if the `Any` contains that type, and returns an optional containing the value, or nil if it contained some other type.

If you put an optional into an `Any`, and try to then extract it as a non-optional, it will fail and return nil, because the type you put in is not the same as the type you are trying get out.

If instead you use `as` without a question mark, this forces the extraction without wrapping it in an optional, and, you guessed it, will blow up at runtime if it’s ever wrong.  In fact this is so dangerous while looking innocent that in the new 1.2 beta version of Swift, it’s been replaced with `as!`, to match its force-unwrapping nature.  In your first example, you put in an `NSImage?`, you’re extracting a non-optional `NSImage`, and using `as`, so you get a runtime assertion.

Anyway, an `Any!` combines all of the above features into one delightful spring-loaded deathtrap.  It will merrily take an optional type, and then allow you to extract its contents as a non-optional without a check.  That is what’s happening in your code – you’re putting an optional into an `Any!`, and then extracting it as a non-optional.  This is almost certainly a bad idea as it will crash if your image file is ever not found, so you are much better off using the code at the very start of this answer to extract the value from the image.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I see now that (if I'm correct) in the first example I was trying to cast **Optional** into a NSImage. Coming back to an example: is there a simple way to get back the NSImage from Any without declaring it also as optional (`var tmp: Any? = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)`), because that's probably my real problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because `NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)` returns an *Optional*. If you look at the documentation you can see that the signature is:

> `init?(byReferencingFile filename: String)`

The question mark after `init` means that the initializer can fail, and that it returns an *Optional* value. So when for example the file does not exist, it will return `nil` instead of an `NSImage` instance.

You can `fix` this by doing this ...

```
var tmp: Any = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath)
var img: NSImage? = tmp as? NSImage
```

... It is not really a fix though.

Your second example works because you force unwrap the optional using `Any!`. You basically say, ignore what the optional's value is, just give me the image that it wraps. But, this will crash if the image could not be loaded.

Ideally what you want to do is this:

```
if let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: somePath) {
    // Here the "if let" has checked and unwrapped the optional
    // and you can be sure that image is not nil.
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the anser, yes it helps! Because of Any I've completely missed the fact that Any was not a NSImage but an Optional. The proposed "fix" (yes I know I should not do it this way, but it's only a theoretical question) with `var img: NSImage? = tmp as? NSImage` i think it will always assign a nil value to the **img** variable even if the **tmp** var was containing a valid NSImage